What is the quantum equation of motion for a massless scalar field in $x^\pm = t\pm x$ coordinates?
Consider a massless scalar field in 1+1D. The Heisenberg equation of motion is
$$ 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = i [H, \phi]. 
$$
Further, since the spacetime translations are implemented by $U =e^{i P^\mu a_\mu}$; differentiating $U^\dagger \phi(x,t) U$ with respect to $x$ gives
$$ 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} =-i[P, \phi]. 
$$
Let us now transform to null coordinates $x^\pm = t\pm x$. Since $\partial_\mu \phi$ is a covector, we can obtain the derivatives in new coordinates to be
$$ 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^{-}} = i [P^{+}, \phi],\quad \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^{+}} = i [P^{-}, \phi] \tag{1}
$$
where $P^\pm = \tfrac{1}{2} (H\pm P)$. Now following Peskin and Schroeder, chapter 1, scalar field equation of motion is same as the classical one; here the mass is zero, so $$(\partial_t^2  - \partial_x^2)\phi=0 \tag{2}.$$ Just by doing coordinate transformations to the null coordinates, this equation would look like
$$
\partial_+ \partial_- \phi = 0. \tag{3; expectation}
$$
The issue is, if I try to use (1) to explicitly check this, I find that
$$
\partial_+ \partial_- \phi = -[P^-, [P^+, \phi]] \sim (H\phi P - P\phi H) \neq 0. \tag{4}
$$
Here I've expanded $P^\pm$ in terms of $H, P$, and used (2) in the form $[H,[H,\phi]] = [P, [P, \phi]]$. In fact, using EoM again from here doesn't take me to a better place.
However, if I add the reversed version of derivatives,
$$
(\partial_+ \partial_- + \partial_- \partial_+ )\phi = 0 \tag{5; result?}
$$
which is surprising as it suggests that partial derivatives don't commute.
It is certain that (2) is correct. If (3) same as (2), then how does one explain (4) being non-zero? Should (5) be the correct equation of motion?
